# Eyefinity resolution on third monitor

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, eyefinity

I'm now using three monitors with resolution capability of 1920x1080.
The one monitor connected to Active Display Port is (from some reason) limited to 1440x900.

Is there a way to increase the resolution of the third monitor to have all three at 1920X1080?

My machine:

- Graphics card - AMD 5770
- Processor - Intel Core i7-2600
- Ram - 8GB
- OS - Windows 7 64bit.

VGC(Video Graphics Controller) driver is up to date.

Got this message:
[image]

Comment: Have you switched that monitor to one of the DVI ports to see if it registers the higher resolution?

Comment: Thanks, each monitor (as stand alone) works perfect at the high resolution of 1920x1080. Sam

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried manual sensing of the displays and then forcing the resolution on the displays from the Catalyst control Panel?

It could also be that it won't allow you to use the display at full res until you combine it into an Ifinity Display. Which will make 3 monitors act as one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply a. Have manualy setting the display, but the resolution ruler does't goes up above 1440x900.
b. Shure I'm trying to group all three together, the problem is that the resolution of other two displays reduces also to 1440x900 (all together= 4320x900).
My aim is to have a grouped displays of 5760x1080.
Sam

Answer (score 0):

is not the displayport who is making the problem but it's your screen resolution is limited to each one to 1440 x 900 if you want a better resolution you have to upgrade your screens  to a better resolution like 1440 x 1080

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that all three monitors work fine by themselves, it is probably an issue with the adapter. Either it has a limitation or it doesn't communicate properly with the monitor.